# Unable to find error in the code for decimal to binary conversion

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void turn_binary(int, int, int);

int main() {
    int n;
    int binary = 0;

    printf("Enter the number:");
    scanf("%d", & n);
    int m = n;
    int c = 0;

    while (m != 0) {
        int d;
        d = m % 2;

        if (d == 0) {
            c++;
        }

        if (d != 0) {
            break;
        }
        m = m / 2;
    }

    turn_binary(n, binary, c);
    return 0;
}

void turn_binary(int a, int b, int c)
{

    int d;
    int j = a;
    
    while (j >= 1)
    {
        int d;
        d = j % 2;
        b = b * 10 + d;
        j = j / 2;
    }

    int rev = 0;
    int k = b;

    while (k != 0)
    {
        int s;
        s = k % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + s;
        k = k / 10;
    }

    int i = 1;
    printf("%d", rev);

    while (i <= c)
    {
        printf("%d", 0);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Actually this is the code I was using for converting a decimal into binary number.
But I am unable to understand the mistake in this code. I mean it is showing no error first of all. The problem I am facing is that for many numbers it is showing correct outputs and for many it is showing wrong outputs.
By examining with different inputs I think that above the decimal number 1100 all the odd numbers are giving wrong outputs. And all the even numbers are giving correct output always.

Some specific problems are like when I am giving 8000,2248 or 1005 it is showing correct outputs but in case of 2247, 2249 or any other decimal odd integer above will give wrong output I guess.

What I have done is just repetitive division with 2 and then I counted the number of zero remainders till the first non zero remainder comes. Then I just formed a binary number *b* starting with the first non zero remainder from the top.

Then I inverted the binary number *b* to obtain the binary number *rev* and then I just wrote the number of zeros I have counted at first behind *rev*.

This way I should get my final binary conversion.

**Please help in finding the mistake.**

Comment: What is this loop inside `main`?

Comment: State a specific input, like “13”,  for which the program fails. State the exact output it produces and the exact output you expect instead. When you write “above 1100”, we do not know if that means a number above decimal 1100 or a number above binary 1100. So showing the exact characters of the input is important.

Comment: If you are overflowing the number of digits that can be represented on an `int`, stop using an `int` to hold the “binary”. Use an array of characters.

Comment: #Eric Postpischill please see the edited part.

Comment: What does "converting a decimal into binary number" mean? It appears you want to read a decimal number (`scanf` will do that for you), then convert it to a binary string representation? How do you output it?